# Scala-Spark Different Results

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to make triplets of a data that I have, based on events, so for this purpose I use `DataFrames`.

```
val w = Window.partitionBy(args(1)).orderBy(args(2))

val lastDf = df.withColumn("OnePreviousEvent", lag(df(args(3)), 1).over(w))
  .withColumn("twoPreviousEvent", lead(df(args(3)), 1).over(w))
  .withColumn("new", concat_ws(",", $"OnePreviousEvent", col(event), $"twoPreviousEvent"))
  .where($"twoPreviousEvent".isNotNull && $"OnePreviousEvent".isNotNull)
  .groupBy("new").agg(count("new").alias("tripCount")).sort($"tripCount".desc)
```

What I want to ask is - every time I run this code, I get different results. Any idea about why this happens would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing strange about it. Let's look at the sample of your code, replacing `args(1..3)` with `x`, y`and`z` to make it easier to analyze:

```
val x: Column
val y: Column
val z: Column

val w = Window.partitionBy(x).orderBy(y)

val lastDf = df.withColumn("OnePreviousEvent", lag(z, 1).over(w))
  .withColumn("twoPreviousEvent", lead(z), 1).over(w))
```

The window uses ordering by `y`, while you use `lag` of `z`. If there are ties in `z` the result is non-deterministic. For example if data:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 4)
).toDF("x", "y", "z")
```

then there are 24 different possible orderings:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 4, 3), (1, 3, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4, 2), ...
```

each satisfying `PARTITION BY x` and `ORDER BY y`.

Ordering will be unique and stable if, and only if all `y` values are unique.